# Python dictionary prints values different to values printed individually

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
validclubs = {}
with open("validclubs2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        id, club = line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit = 1)
        validclubs[int(id)] = id
        validclubs[(club)] = club


print(validclubs)
```

Where validclubs.txt is in the format:

```
1234 Joe Bloggs
2345 Mark
345 John James Smith
```

I want the dictionary to be in the form:

```
{'1234':'Joe Bloggs', '2345':'Mark', '345':'John James Smith'}
```

If I print `validclubs[int(id)]` I get:

```
1234
2345
345
```

If I print `validclubs[(club)]` I get:

```
Joe Bloggs
Mark
John James Smith
```

but if I print `validclubs`, I get:

```
{1234: '1234', 'Joe Bloggs': 'Joe Bloggs', '2345': '2345', 'Mark': 'Mark', '345': '345', 'John James Smith': 'John James Smith'}
```

I am absolutely baffled as to how any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! `validclubs[id] = club` seems sufficient, no?

Comment: @ggorlen yes, that is true, thank you, although still the same problem absolutely boggling my mind. I'm sure it is just a simple fix but I can't see it anywhere.

Comment: Did you remove the two other assignment lines? If you set `id` as a key and value and also set `club` as a key and value, then it's no surprise when the dictionary has both pairs as keys and values. If you only want to associate `id`s and `club`s, then the above code is all you need to do that.

Comment: No, the code is exactly as it is the only thing I have changed is I added a `print()` after the two assignment statements one being `print validclubs[int(id)]` the other `print validclubs[(club)]`. Sorry are you saying I have assigned `id` as a key and a value? @ggorlen I can't see where I have, I have assigned `id` as key and `club` as value, have I not?

Comment: Get rid of all your prints and all of your `validclub` assignments except for the one I showed. Then print the dict at the end after all the keys and vals have been set.

Comment: OK sorry, I misread your first comment, thank you! Yes this is correct:
`validclubs = {}
with open("validclubs2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        id, club = line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit = 1)
        validclubs[id] = club


print(validclubs)`

Answer (score 0):

Ma dude do this

```
validclub ={}

with open("validclubs.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        id_, club = line.strip("\n").split(maxsplit = 1)
        print("id:"+id_, "club:"+club)
        validclub[id_] = club

print(validclub)
```